# Keyboard shortcuts not working after process attach (Visual Studio 2013 bug during debugging)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, envdte, vsix, vspackage

I've written small VSIX plugin which is able to attach debugger to particular process. This process is written using c# and c++ code, so I need to attach to it using both managed and native engines. From Visual Studio it can be achieved simply by selecting these engines from window opened by *DEBUG -> Attach to process... -> Select...*:

[image]

Below, I've shown the code sample which basically does the same thing, using `Process2.Attach2` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte80.process2.attach2.aspx)):

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
EnvDTE80.Debugger2 dteDebugger = dte.Debugger as EnvDTE80.Debugger2;
EnvDTE80.Transport transport = dteDebugger.Transports.Item("default");
EnvDTE80.Engine[] engines = new[] { transport.Engines.Item("managed/native") };
process.Attach2(engines);
```

Unfortunately, the very same code which **works for VS2012, doesn't work for VS2013 (Update 1)**.

What I've noticed is keyboard problems. Visual Studio doesn't react for pressing key shortcuts. For example, if I press *F10*, debugger does nothing. If I want to step over any breakpoint, I need to use mouse instead and access context menu: *DEBUG -> Step Over*, etc.

It's annoying, I need the keyboard to control debugger. Has anyone noticed this problem and solved it already?

**BTW**: If I use *managed* engine only (`transport.Engines.Item("managed")`), the keyboard starts to work correctly. But because I need to debug through unmanaged code also, I need additional engine - the *native* one.

**EDIT:** I've [reported it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/823470/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-after-process-attach-visual-studio-bug-during-debugging) also to Microsoft Connect network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found temporary workaround. To fix that issue I opened *TOOLS -> Options... -> Debugging -> General* and checked *Use Managed Compatibility Mode* option:

[image]

What's more, this change paradoxically fixes another, seemingly unrelated issue, namely evaluation of expressions in *Watch* or *Immediate* windows for some particular cases (which I also noticed few days ago).

**UPDATE:**

I've detected this issue using Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013, Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1

After installation of Version 12.0.30219.00 Update 2 CTP, this problem is no longer reproducible for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Jarek mentioned above, this issue shouldn't repro in [Update 2 CTP 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42023). If you are still encountering it, please reactivate the [Connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/823470/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-after-process-attach-visual-studio-bug-during-debugging)